# Calculate mean square displacements for different particles from a excel file

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, matrix

I have the particle movement data in the following format:

```
{
 {1., 1., 0., 0.},
 {1., 2., 0.240727, 0.974106},
 {1., 3., 0.0215366, 0.703085},
 {1., 4., 0.437541, 1.19085},
 {2., 1., 0., 0.},
 {2., 2., -2.17808, 0.455328},
 {2., 3., -2.97556, -0.668351},
 {2., 4., -3.91848, -1.25396},
 {3., 1., 0., 0.},
 {3., 2., -0.523589, 0.136621},
 {3., 3., -1.87956, 0.679403},
 {3., 4., -2.36116, 0.749859}
}
```

The first number is the particle number, second is the frame number in the movie, third is the $x$ position, and the fourth is the $y$-position. So in the above data, the first 4 lists belong to particle 1, the next 4 to particle 2 and the last 4 to particle 3.

I need to calculate the mean square displacement (MSD) $(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2$ for each of the particles separately. I can calculate MSD if I don't have to care about the above data having 3 particles, treat all as the same (but that's not what I want). I need to calculate MSD for each of these particles separately. Basically, somehow I have to tell the program where the the data for particle 1 end and where data for particle 2 starts.

In MATLAB, I have used the `find` function to return the location index of the number "1" in the second column of the data and run the loop till that index to calculate MSD for each particle.

I am new to *Mathematica* and trying to learn it. It's taking me a while to find a answer to this problem. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

Let's break down the task step by step.

1. Separate the data for the different particles: `GatherBy`
2. Sort data by frame number (not really necessary as it's sorted, but let's do it anyway): `SortBy`
3. Extract the positions and calculate the MSD.

I have your data stored in the variable `data`.

`GatherBy[data, First]` separates into sublists having the same first element (same particle). Let's take the first sublist, `sublist = First@GatherBy[data, First]`.

`sublist  = SortBy[sublist, #[[2]]&]` sorts the sublist by the second element (frame number).

Now take the difference of sequential coordinates, take the squared norm of that difference, and calculate the mean: `Mean[#.#& /@ sublist[[All, {3,4}]] ]`.

Putting it all together:

```
gatheredData = GatherBy[data, First];

msd = Function[sublist, 
  Mean[#.# & /@ 
    Differences@SortBy[sublist, #[[2]] &][[All, {3, 4}]]
  ]
] /@ gatheredData
```

You may wish to pair up this list of results with the particle indices:

```
Transpose[{gatheredData[[All, 1, 1]], msd}]

(* ==> {{1., 0.513101}, {2., 2.69401}, {3., 0.887661}} *)
```

Again, this is not necessary if your list was originally sorted by particle index, but it's important if it wasn't.

---

Recommended reading to understand this code:

- [`Map` and list manipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ApplyingFunctionsToPartsOfExpressions.html)
- [Pure functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html)
- [List indexing (`Part`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do get most of it. I still get confused by the syntaxes in mathematica, but I will read the documentation and try to make complete sense of this.

Comment: @Anjil It's helpful to read code from "outside to inside".  First just look at `Function[...] /@ gatheredData`.  Now try t understand what that function does by using it on a single element of `gatheredData`.  You'll see that that's just what I wrote in the first part of the answer.  Keep moving inward in the expression to understand what's going on.

Comment: I posted a similar quetsion here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112100/performance-of-list-manipulation-for-means-squared-displacement and would be very happy if you could help me. The user BlacKow gave a very nice answer based on you answer here, but I have the feeling that it is not fully correct. E.g. I need the Mean of x^2 +y^2 and found out that there might be a problem. Please see my comment: http://imgur.com/8BAX4pe . Thank you in advance.

Comment: I posted a similar gestion: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112100/performance-of-list-manipulation-for-means-squared-displacement and would be  happy if you could help. User BlacKow gave a nice answer based on you answer, but I have the feeling that it is not fully correct. I need the Mean of xdiff^2 +ydiff^2 and found out that there is  a problem. Please see here: http://imgur.com/8BAX4pe  I compared the result based on your code with Pythons well known trackpy package, and there is a difference: soft-matter.github.io/trackpy . My Table code produces exactly the same results.

Comment: @mrz I won't be able to spend much time here until Tuesday.  Can you remind me then please?

Comment: I set a bounty to ask to help to solve my similar question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112100/performance-of-list-manipulation-for-means-squared-displacement. Very interesting is e.g. the fast FFT code.